# How to call different JQuery functions from a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdownbox

How do you bind each item in a dropdownlist to a different JQuery function?

For example I have a dropdown with different report names, I want each time you select the drop down to trigger a new report to display.

I accomplished this before with just straight text links with `<a href="#" id="btnReport1">Report 1</a>` which called `$("#btnReport1").bind("click", function () {...}`

I want to call the same function above from each of the different report items in the dropdownlist. There will be 5 or so I'll need to call. Is there a way to embed a link in each item? Do I use "change" somehow over "click" ?

I'm using Razor and MVC.Net so I could do something like `@Html.DropdownList(...)` with a SelectList object and put code in the controller file if need be. But I prefer to handle this on the HTML though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you're trying to bind to a `select` dropdown. the best way to accomplish this is the `onChange()` handler ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for details).

from there, you would simply determine which option had been selected based on the current value (probably obtained [via the `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) and perform an action based on that value, using an series of if statements or another method.

Comment: Could I do $("#reportDropdown").bind("change", function(){... or would it be .change(... ?

Comment: @DerekR the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method is actually preferred as of jQuery v1.7 (see [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)), so I would recommend using `$("#reportDropdown").on('change' function(){...})` — but yes, the three are interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used .Change() and did the basic var selectedValue = $(".reportNamesDropdown").val(); and used a series of if-else statements to handle it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a single function on the click event and have it look at the value and decide what specific report to load from there.